# Why should I use the esc_url?

Tags: security

This thing makes my coding difficult.
Wordpress codex reasons the use of esc_url by talking vaguely about security.
But is it really worth the trouble?

For example, what's the important, practical security benefit by using

```
<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>
```

instead of

```
<?php echo home_url() ?>
```

PS: I am not talking about theme development, but about a specific site.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you check the documentation on [Data Validation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation#URLs) it has following to say about the function:

> Always use esc_url when sanitizing URLs (in text nodes, attribute nodes or anywhere else). Rejects URLs that do not have one of the provided whitelisted protocols [...], eliminates invalid characters, and removes dangerous characters.

There you have it — practical security benefit. Valid protocol, no murky characters.

The answer about necessity is firmly **yes**. Escaping output is the most basic security practice.

Comment: With all due respect, I can not see how the home link for example can pose a security risk. Maybe these guidelines are for theme creation and do not apply for "private" code? After all, it may be best to hardcode the home address and other links in html and not use php at all if there are security risks?

Comment: It is vastly more productive to apply security practices consistently and universally, than debate if each and every case is worth it. :)

Comment: On the other hand a [resource](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/data-sanitization-and-validation-with-wordpress--wp-25536) suggested by [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation#External_Resources) establishes **Rule No. 3: Trust WordPress**. This seems to recommend against oversanitizing wp core functions like `home_url()`, if used in their proper context. According to this recommendation, I would have expected `home_url` to perform its own sanitization.

Comment: Sry, I am quite new to this topic, but may anybody give an example, where home_url() or maybe get_permalink() (where as far as I know esc_url() should be used too) returns an invalid or unsanitized (?) url? I don't want to be lazy or stubborn, therefore an example might help me understand the usage.

Answer (score 3):

Another things must be keep in your head about
`esc_url()` is for something like `<a href="SANITIZE_THIS_URL">your_text</a>`.if you’re going to use the URL in your HTML output, like a href attribute for a link, or a src attribute for an image element, you should use `esc_url()`.

`esc_url_raw()`is for other cases where you want a clean URL, but you don’t want HTML entities to be encoded. So any non-HTML usage (DB, redirect) would use this.

The `esc_url_raw()` function will do pretty much the same as `esc_url()`, but it will not decode entities, meaning it will not replace & with &#038 and so on. As Mark pointed out, it’s safe to use `esc_url_raw()` in database queries, redirects and HTTP functions, such as `wp_remote_get()'
for more info about [esc_url_raw()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url_raw)

Answer (score 3):

well, all user input should be sanitized...
If the url you inject is not user input (e.g. site setting by someone you fully trust, hardcoded values) then you may relief yourself from esc-url.

but if I could inject that url to your site, i could easily inject js code, or redirection code... or even server side code in some situations.

this can lead to session hijacking and your users accounts being stolen and other bad options.

### Edit:

In your example `esc_url( home_url( '/' ) );`
it operated on a semi-hardcoded value! therefore `esc_url` can be eliminated.
That said I still don't see why bother distinctions between when there is a threat and when there is not and generally would suggest to keep esc_url() for every value.

Comment: "Site setting by someone you trust" is _still literally_ user input. :)

Comment: @Rarst yeah, I am with you, but he was so "disgusted" by using esc_url, I have been bit more forgiving.

Answer (score 1):

[esc_url](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url) is used to produce a valid HTML (not to sanitize input). You should use this anytime you are not 100% sure that what you want to output is a valid HTML for that context.

Comment: All family of escaping functions are explicitly for sanitizing.